# Query with ransack: how to get no results by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ransack

I would like my page to have no results by  default.

I would like to achieve the same like when I add .none to result but still after parameters are set result are shown.
How can i achieve that?

```
def index
 @search = SomeClass.all
 @items = @search.result.page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want your index page to display no records when you first load the view (and when the filters are empty). This could result in returning too many records and the user would experience a very slow loading page.

One way to address this is to make sure you execute the search query **only** if search parameters are passed to the action.

### In your controller

```
def index
 # we define the search but we don't execute it right away
 search
 # execute the search query only if search params exists
 items(params[:page],10) if search_params 
end

private

def items(page,per=10)
  @items ||= search.result(page).per(per)
end 

def search
  @search ||= SomeClass.search(search_param)
end

def search_param
  params[:q]
end
```

### In your view

Now you can safely reference @search, it will always be defined in your view.
On the other hand, @items, might or might not be defined so you have to handle both cases in your view.
For example in haml:

```
.row
  = @items.nil? ? (render 'no_results') : (render 'results')
```

Answer (score 3):

Likely a better solution, use `.none` instead of `.all`.

```
def index
  search_params = params[:q]
  query_base = search_params.present? ? Model.all : Model.none
  @search = query_base.ransack(search_params)
  @records = @search.result
end
```